# Test flash message created by number_field ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, form-for

Trying to write an acceptance to test for error messages displayed. I'm having trouble with testing for number_field type in form_for.

Group - Index.html.erb

```
 <div class='row'>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
      <%= f.label :size %>
      <%= f.number_field :size, in: 1..12 %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that number_field prevents the form to submit if the input is not between 1 and 12. It displays a flash message of how the number has to be between 1 and 12.

Because the form isn't submitting at all, my flash[:error] in the controller doesn't get hit. I'm not quite sure how to test for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

With Capybara/RSpec you could at least write something like:

```
visit my_form_path
fill_in ... # all the other stuff on the form
select '99', from: 'size'
click_button 'Submit' #or whatever the submit button is called
expect(page).to_not have_content(...) #text on page rendered if form submit works
expect(page).to have_content(...) #text on the form the user should still be on
```

You are right that you will never see the flash if the browser supports HTML5. Capybara supports different browser engines, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know if it supports any that emulate older browsers. If that happened to be the case, you could swap in an old browser and you'd presumably see the flash.

Comment: The above works in the context that Capybara will doesn't support HTML5 so it actually submits the form. But from the users perspective, acceptance testing, they don't actually submit the form so writing a test for the latter case of capybara submitting the test would in would false from the users perspective.

Comment: I would suggest using the Selenium driver but I don't think Firefox supports this element. I wonder if you could use that and a polyfill, but I am out if my depth at that point.https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills